# how to access blank cells from excel file using apache-tika

Tags: java, excel, apache-tika

I am using **Apache-Tika-1.13** to read and work with the excel file contents, I am working good with it but I have problem when I access excel file that contains blank cells. I need to access that blank cells, do **Tika** provides any way to access blank cells with it's latest release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apache Tika provides a consistent, easy to use and simplified view across a wide range of file formats. As such, not everything possible with the underlying libraries is possible with Tika.

You'll need to step down to Apache POI, the library that Tika uses for Excel files, if you want fine-grained control over blank and missing cells. Then, [see the POI documentation on iterating over cells, including with missing/blank cell control](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) for how to do what you want

Comment: I have implemented it using SheetContentsHandler and OPCPackage, Thanks for reply.